# Customize file colors in ranger terminal file manager

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, ranger

I've been using [ranger](https://ranger.github.io/) for a couple of days now, and I started customizing it to my needs. I have now the devicons plugin which shows a glyphs next the file name, but I don't know where I can change the color the file name.

I assume it should be in color schema (I'm using a modified `Solarized.py`), but how can say that I want all files ending in `txt` to have a green foreground color?

Comment: Someone asked a similar question [here](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Official-user-guide) but I couldn't fully understand the responses. There's reference to "LS_COLORS theme" which may provide the feature sometime in the future. Whether is will be part of the latest version of Ranger, or whether older versions of Ranger will be able to use it is not clear to me.

Comment: See https://github.com/ranger/colorschemes/issues/5 as well.